# Check whether switch case is chosen

Tags: java, c#

I have an exercise that using switch case. Assuming the code like

```
int choice;
do {

  choice = //user input here;

  switch (choice) {
   case 1: //print something; break;
   case 2: //print something; break;
   case 3: //print something; break;
   default: //print default; break;
  }
} while(condition);
```

i want the user can only choose the case once. If they did choose case 1, they cannot choose that again.

Comment: is this `Java` or `C#` or `Any`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a private bool variable for each one of your options and set it true if user called each one. Then check whether its true before running that option codes, again.

For example:

```
bool _case1=false;
int choice;
do{
choice = //user input here;
switch(choice){
   case 1: 
     if(!_case1) 
      {
        //print something; 
        _case1=true; 
      } 
     else
      {
        //Tell the user "You have selected this option once"
      }    
     break;
     //etc

}
}while(condition);
```

Comment: thank you very much !!! And the C# way using List<> also works too

Answer (score 0):

You could call methods for each case and have some bools that mark whether each case has already been chosen, use an if statement to check if the case has already been chosen and if so print a notice to pick another, otherwise perform the action.

You could also do this without separate methods but I am a fan of modular code. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that a function that contains this switch case is called over and over again. If you want such a functionality, I would point to [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Use the set to store the choices. If a set already contains a certain choice, take whatever action you deem fit.

Using a set is better than having a global array of booleans, since that could potentially be wasting a lot of memory, depending on the number of choices that you have.

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

When user press the input

if the input is match case then 
     store this input in one List.

Next time you have to `check this input`.

If it belongs in List or not,

if belongs then case will not execute 
if not belongs then it will execute the case.

Try in this way :

```
List<Integer> choiceList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int choice;
do {
  choice = //user input here;

  if (choiceList.contains(choice)) {
    continue;
  }

  choiceList.add(choice);

  switch(choice) {
    case 1: //print something; break;
    case 2: //print something; break;
    case 3: //print something; break;
    default: //print default; break;
  }
} while(condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

As some of the other answers have said you can use a `boolean` to check if a case has been used or not. However, you can also use an `int`. The advantage of using an `int` is that you can specify how many times each case can be used. For example, the following code can only use each case once.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;
        int case1 = 0, case2 = 0, case3 = 0;
        int case1lim = 1, case2lim = 1, case3lim = 1;

        System.out.println("You may use may enter the number 1 " + case1lim + " times");
        System.out.println("You may use may enter the number 2 " + case2lim + " times");
        System.out.println("You may use may enter the number 3 " + case3lim + " times");

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 3");
            choice = user_input.nextInt();

            if(choice == 1 && case1 < case1lim || choice == 2 && case2 < case2lim || choice == 3 && case3 < case3lim) {
                switch(choice){
                   case 1: //print something; 
                             case1++;
                             break;
                   case 2: //print something; 
                             case2++;
                             break;
                   case 3: //print something;
                             case3++;
                             break;
                   default: //print default; 
                             break;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please pick another number since you have already used that case or you entered a bad value");
            }
        } while(true);
    }
}
```

However if you change the values of the line

```
int case1lim = 1, case2lim = 1, case3lim = 1;
```

to

```
int case1lim = 2, case2lim = 1, case3lim = 1;
```

You can use the first case twice and all the other cases once.